# Replace hstore with json by creating a column variable using NEW #= in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, hstore

I was searching for creating a column/variable in postgres and I found out a code that is using `hsstore` extension to create a column variable.

I found out this code

```
    temp_sql_string:='"'||p_k||'"=>"'||nextval(seq::regclass)||'"';
    NEW := NEW #= temp_sql_string :: public.hstore;
```

from : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger

Now, what i want is to get rid of the hstore extension and I want to use json.
I've tried using this but doesn't work.

```
temp_sql_string:='"'||p_k||'":"'||nextval(seq::regclass)||'"';          
NEW := NEW #= temp_sql_string::json;
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#=` operator is specific for hstore. Use `json(b)_populate_record()` as a JSON(B) equivalent:

```sql
new:= json_populate_record(new, json_build_object(key, value));
```

`temp_sql_string` is not a valid JSON representation due to the lack of curly braces. In general, you should avoid interpolating variables in JSON strings by using appropriate functions instead. Assuming `p_k` and `seq` are text variables, this should work fine:

```sql
new:= json_populate_record(new, json_build_object(p_k, nextval(seq::regclass)));
```

Comment: still having this error 
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Expected end of input, but found ":".

Comment: See the updated answer.